# Unable to capture authentication handshake using airodump-ng

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-12.04, network-monitoring, aircrack-ng

I am using airodump-ng to capture authentication handshake, so I ran airodump for almost 49 minutes and the output appearing as

```
CH  9 ][ Elapsed: 49 mins ][ 2013-04-14 10:58 ][ fixed channel prism0: -1                                 

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID                        

 04:18:0F:9B:38:99    2 100    28948      457    0   6  54 . WPA2 CCMP   PSK  AndroidAP                    

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost  Packets  Probes
```

But as mentioned on the [wiki page](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa#troubleshooting_tips) of aircrack I should be receiving `wpa handshake message`.

So please help me where I am doing wrong

set of commands:

```
# echo 1 | tee /proc/brcm_monitor0  //Switching my wifi in monitor mode
# airmon-ng start prism0            //using airmon-ng to make sure wifi in monitor mode
# airodump-ng prism0                //gives details about neighborhood wifi
 CH -1 ][ Elapsed: 24 s ][ 2013-04-14 09:48                                    

 BSSID              PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSID

 04:18:0F:9B:38:99    2      242        0    0   6  54 . WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Andro

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost  Packets  Probes
```

Then I used

```
# airodump-ng -c 9 --bssid 04:18:0F:9B:38:99 -w psk prism0
```

which gives the output previously mentioned.

So please let me know where I am wrong because after searching on net I found it won't take much time to gather authentication handshake but I did't get anything after 49 minutes.

my wifi card is: `Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365]`

Comment: It says you're listening on channel 9, but your AP is beaconing channel 6. (This can happen on overlapping 2.4GHz channels). Sniff on channel 6 if your AP is on channel 6. Also make sure the separate client device you're looking for is joining the 2.4GHz band of the AP, if the AP supports multiple bands simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa#step_2_-_start_airodump-ng_to_collect_authentication_handshake)

Look at the link you mentioned: There is no connected wireless clients -> No handshaking

Comment: Hey how I can be connected to wifi prior to wpa key. 
I am using aircrack for this purpose only??